# Parse Columns in SQL by delimiter

Tags: sql-server, parsing, join, delimiter

In SQL Server, I have a table/view that has multiple columns. The last column looks like this:

```
COL
---------------------------------
|test|test|test11|testing|final
|test|test|test1|testing2|final3
|test|test|test17|testing|final6
```

How do parse this column by `|` and combine it with the right side of the existing table like such:

```
COL1     COL2                                COL     Parse1    Parse2    Parse3   Parse4    Parse5
   1        4    |test|test|test11|testing|final       test      test    test11  testing     final
   2        6   |test|test|test1|testing2|final3       test      test    test1  testing2    final3
   5        9   |test|test|test17|testing|final6       test      test    test17  testing    final6
```

There are the same number of parsings for column `COL`.

Any help would be great thanks!

Comment: This is an absolutely awful way to handle data. It violates 1NF with multiple values in a single tuple. You are going to have to split this with a splitter. Here is my personal favorite. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/ Some other excellent alternatives can be found here. https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not clear if you have a leading `|` in the field `COL`.  If so, you may want to shift `/x[n]`

The pattern is pretty clear.  Easy to expand or contract as necessary

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([COL] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('test|test|test11|testing|final')
,('test|test|test1|testing2|final3')
,('test|test|test17|testing|final6')

Select A.* 
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Pos1 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos2 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos3 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos4 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos5 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos6 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos7 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos8 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[8]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos9 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[9]','varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(A.Col,'|','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as B1
             ) B
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: Upvoting but if you are on 2016 or higher, consider converting it to JSON. Although i haven't tested it, a number of colleagues have told me it has a significant performance increase over XML.

Comment: @NickKnauer Happy to help

Comment: @ColdSolstice I've heard the same, but I have yet to witness this.  Now that I'm thinking of it, I'll perform some benchmarks and let you know.... later :)